# How do I display a string property?

Tags: powershell

In the scenario below, how do I use a .NET method to display the `pscomputername` property, returned by Get-DnsServerForwarder?

```
Get-DnsServerForwarder -ComputerName db3testads001 | gm

EnableReordering          Property       bool EnableReordering {get;set;}
PSComputerName            Property       string PSComputerName {get;}
```

Comment: Is this more of a programming question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Either of these examples should work:

```
(Get-DnsServerForwarder -ComputerName db3testads001).PSComputerName
```

or

```
$value = Get-DnsServerForwarder -ComputerName db3testads001
$value.PSComputerName
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cmdlet returns multiple instances and you want to capture the `PSComputerName` property from each, you could also just "drop" them in the pipeline like this:

```
Get-DnsServerForwarder -ComputerName db3testads001 |ForEach-Object { $_.PSComputerName }
```

This would return an array of strings instead of a single string

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array with the computer name you would use:

```
Get-DnsServerForwarder -ComputerName db3testads001 | Select -ExpandProperty PSComputerName
```

If you just want the first one in the result set you can add `-First 1` to the Select statement